# Personal game creation refuses to work (C Programming)

Tags: c

I have been debugging my Fallout Lockpick Simulator for a couple days now and had no progress. Every time I load this game up and type in a degree to move the bobby pin, it says I win. Instead, the game should loop until *win* is set to 1 and then say I win. What is preventing my program from accomplishing this? Full code is listed below. Thanks!

```
// Fallout Lockpick Sim
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void command(int *newWin, int key);

main()
{
    time_t t;
    char stillPlay;
    int win;
    int key;

    do {
            system("cls");
            win = 0;
            srand(time(&t));
            key = (rand() % 359);
            lockface();
            command(&win, key);
            printf("You Won!!!\n");
            printf("Do you want to play again?");
            scanf(" %c", &stillPlay);
    } while (toupper(stillPlay) == 'Y');

    return;
}

lockface()
{
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /         \\ \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf("  \\         / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

void command(int *newWin, int key)
{
    int cmd;

    do {
    printf("Angle:");
    scanf(" %d", &cmd);
    if ((cmd >= 0 && cmd <= 21) || (cmd >= 338 && cmd <= 359))
    {
        system("cls");
        face0();
        if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10)
        {
            *newWin = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (cmd >= 22 && cmd <= 67)
    {
        system("cls");
        face45();
        if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10)
        {
            *newWin = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (cmd >= 68 && cmd <= 112)
    {
        system("cls");
        face90();
        if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10)
        {
            *newWin = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (cmd >= 113 && cmd <= 157)
    {
        system("cls");
        face135();
        if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10)
        {
            *newWin = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (cmd >= 158 && cmd <= 202)
    {
        system("cls");
        face180();
        if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10)
        {
            *newWin = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (cmd >= 203 && cmd <= 247)
    {
        system("cls");
        face225();
        if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10)
        {
            *newWin = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (cmd >= 248 && cmd <= 292)
    {
        system("cls");
        face270();
        if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10)
        {
            *newWin = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (cmd >= 293 && cmd <= 337)
    {
        system("cls");
        face315();
        if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10)
        {
            *newWin = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not valid command!");
        exit(1);
    }
    } while (*newWin != 1);
}

face0()
{
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /  |  \\ \n");
    printf("  /    |    \\ \n");
    printf(" |     |     | \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf("  \\         / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

face45()
{
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /      /  \\ \n");
    printf(" |     /     | \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf("  \\         / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

face90()
{
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /         \\ \n");
    printf(" |      _____| \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf("  \\         / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

face135()
{
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /         \\ \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf(" |      \\    | \n");
    printf("  \\      \\  / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

face180()
{
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /         \\ \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf(" |      |    | \n");
    printf("  \\    |    / \n");
    printf("    \\ _|_ / \n");
}

face225()
{
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /         \\ \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf(" |     /     | \n");
    printf("  \\ /       / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

face270()
{
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /         \\ \n");
    printf(" |______     | \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf("  \\         / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

face315()
{
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /  \\      \\ \n");
    printf(" |     \\     | \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf("  \\         / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}
```

Comment: Where's the main function? I don't see a correctly defined one

Comment: Make sure you've saved out your latest changes, and that you've re-compiled and re-linked it.  You may be running an earlier version without realizing it.  The safest thing is to delete the executable and any object files prior to rebuilding it.  That way you're guaranteed not to be picking up anything stale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it works. I use Ubuntu Linux so I can't use the `system` call and I added a break at `330` so that the program will inform you that you won if you enter `330` or approximately that.

```
// Fallout Lockpick Sim
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void command(int *newWin, int key);

face0() {
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /  |  \\ \n");
    printf("  /    |    \\ \n");
    printf(" |     |     | \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf("  \\         / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

face45() {
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /      /  \\ \n");
    printf(" |     /     | \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf("  \\         / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

face90() {
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /         \\ \n");
    printf(" |      _____| \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf("  \\         / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

face135() {
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /         \\ \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf(" |      \\    | \n");
    printf("  \\      \\  / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

face180() {
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /         \\ \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf(" |      |    | \n");
    printf("  \\    |    / \n");
    printf("    \\ _|_ / \n");
}

face225() {
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /         \\ \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf(" |     /     | \n");
    printf("  \\ /       / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

face270() {
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /         \\ \n");
    printf(" |______     | \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf("  \\         / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

face315() {
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /  \\      \\ \n");
    printf(" |     \\     | \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf("  \\         / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

lockface() {
    printf("      ___ \n");
    printf("    /     \\ \n");
    printf("  /         \\ \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf(" |           | \n");
    printf("  \\         / \n");
    printf("    \\ ___ / \n");
}

int main(void) {
    time_t t;
    char stillPlay;
    int win;
    int key;

    do {
        //system("cls");
        win = 0;
        srand((unsigned) time(&t));
        key = (rand() % 359);
        lockface();
        command(&win, key);
        printf("You Won!!!\n");
        printf("Do you want to play again?");
        scanf(" %c", &stillPlay);
    } while (toupper(stillPlay) == 'Y');

    return 0;
}


void command(int *newWin, int key) {
    int cmd;

    do {
        printf("Angle:");
        scanf(" %d", &cmd);
        if ((cmd >= 0 && cmd <= 21) || (cmd >= 338 && cmd <= 359)) {

            face0();
            if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10) {
                *newWin = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (cmd >= 22 && cmd <= 67) {

            face45();
            if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10) {
                *newWin = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (cmd >= 68 && cmd <= 112) {

            face90();
            if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10) {
                *newWin = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (cmd >= 113 && cmd <= 157) {

            face135();
            if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10) {
                *newWin = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (cmd >= 158 && cmd <= 202) {

            face180();
            if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10) {
                *newWin = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (cmd >= 203 && cmd <= 247) {

            face225();
            if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10) {
                *newWin = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (cmd >= 248 && cmd <= 292) {

            face270();
            if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10) {
                *newWin = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (cmd >= 293 && cmd <= 337) {

            face315();
            //if (fabs(key - cmd) <= 10) {
            *newWin = 1;
            //}
        }
        else {
            printf("Not valid command!");
            exit(1);
        }
    } while (*newWin != 1);
}
```

Output

```
      ___ 
    /     \ 
  /         \ 
 |           | 
 |           | 
  \         / 
    \ ___ / 
Angle:90
      ___ 
    /     \ 
  /         \ 
 |      _____| 
 |           | 
  \         / 
    \ ___ / 
Angle:290
      ___ 
    /     \ 
  /         \ 
 |______     | 
 |           | 
  \         / 
    \ ___ / 
Angle:330
      ___ 
    /     \ 
  /  \      \ 
 |     \     | 
 |           | 
  \         / 
    \ ___ / 
You Won!!!
Do you want to play again?
```

In codeblocks and with windows 10, it is the same:

[image]

Comment: So you're saying that the code written as is (minus the Ubuntu Linux remix) is working as should? I am currently using CodeBlocks to code mine. Is this CodeBlocks own error?

Comment: @SamuelF Yes, it worked and it didn't say "You win" every time. It might be something with your environment, but I think it is something with the code. I can also try it with codeblocks if you like, I have a Windows os as well. I can try it with codeblocks to see if I can reproduce the error.

Comment: If it's not an inconvenience then I would be very grateful if you tried it out.

Comment: @SamuelF I tried it with codeblocks and your program works. If I were you I would make a new project with the code and try again. I tested the code and it runs without saying that you win.